# Parsing date with pandas fails in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, parsing

So I have date in format like this

> '05/03/2016 11:40:00 PM'

And I wanna parse it in my Python app. But I'm getting stack while parsing as pandas doesn't accept format I've provided.

I've looked through docs on pandas and on stackoverflow tutorials as well, but no solution from here worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("crimes12-18.csv")
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date)

df['time_hour'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)

df = df[df['year'] != 2017]

df.head()
```

At the end of the day i'm getting such an error

```
ValueError: time data '05/03/2016 11:40:00 PM' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I %p' (match)
```

Comment: Not quite sure what's going on. In the question you seem to be using a different formatting than you are receiving in the error. Regardless seems you just want `format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'`

Comment: @ALollz, I'm still receiving the same error. Look at the screenshot provided below https://snag.gy/jtQ3pL.jpg

Comment: You probably mean to have it be `%m/%d/%Y ...` Not quite sure what the 21st month is.

Comment: @ALollz, you're lifesaver. Thanks a lot it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

So as @ALollz told the problem was with `%m/%d/%Y ...`
finally it worked